# Field that acts both as textfield and combobox

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox, jtextfield

Basically I need a field (for Swing) which lets user enter data if that specified data is not in the list provided in `Combo-box`. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the "Editable Combo Box" on the [swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).

Basically, you need to use `setEditable(true)` for your combo box.  From the API docs:

> Determines whether the JComboBox field is editable. An editable
>   JComboBox allows the user to type into the field or selected an item
>   from the list to initialize the field, after which it can be edited.
>   (The editing affects only the field, the list item remains intact.) A
>   non editable JComboBox displays the selected item in the field, but
>   the selection cannot be modified.

Comment: but i do not want to let the user modify that existing data.. i mean if i do setEditable(true) then whatever the user selects he can modify it and continue.. but i just want this property where in the user can only see if the specified data is there and if its there, he can select it and if its not there, he should be able to enter the value..